# How can I customise how Razor converts values of certain types to text?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, string-formatting

Imagine I have some custom type:

```
public class CustomType
{
    public override string ToString() {
        return "Default";
    }
}
```

Next, imagine I use an instance of this type in a Razor view:

```
@model CustomType

<span>The custom type is @Model</span>
```

Razor seems to use `ToString` to convert the value into text for the resulting HTML. However, I want to tell Razor that whenever it wants to format a `CustomType`, it should use  some given custom formatting logic.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with an HtmlHelper

```
@Html.CustomFormattingLogic(Model)

public static class MyHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomFormattingLogic(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        CustomType model)
    {
        var customString = MethodToDoFormatting(model);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(customString);
    }
}
```

...as another option, you could have an extension method do custom formatting:

```
public static class MyCustomTypeExtensions
{
    public static string CustomFormattingLogic(this CustomType model)
    {
        var customString = MethodToDoFormatting(model);
        return customString;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but it's not as reliable as having the formatting done automatically since a developer could forget to call the method.

Comment: ...and you can't do your custom formatting in the .ToString override?

Comment: I don't own all of the types I would like to provide custom formatting logic for. Also, not all formatting needs are the same; different formatting can be desired for different situations, so using `ToString()` isn't a good general-purpose solution to solve formatting needs for all uses of a type.

Comment: If you have different formatting needs for different situations, you are left with 3 options: HtmlHelper, extension method for your CustomType, or partial view.

Comment: So do you think it's not possible to configure Razor they way I want?

Comment: Without getting into the internals of the razor parser and/or view engine, no.